# how to view record row from grid in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, grid, view

I have successfully created grid in magento admin panel. I can see all records from database successfully but now whenever I will click on any row I get error. I want to display that particular details after clicking. like label and the data from database. how to do that. Here are my `grid.php` file

```
class Demo_Feedback_Block_Adminhtml_Feedback_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function __construct()
    { 
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('id');
        $this->setDefaultSort('id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true); 
    }

    public function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection=Mage::getModel("feedback/feedback")->getCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    public function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('id',
                array(
                        'header'=>$this->__('ID'),
                        'align' =>'right',
                        'width' => '30px',
                        'index' => 'id'
                ));
        $this->addColumn('name',
                array(
                        'header'=>$this->__('NAME'),
                        'index' => 'name'
                ));
        $this->addColumn('guestfeedback',
                array(
                'header'=>$this->__('GUEST FEEDBACK'),
                'index' => 'guestfeedback',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created form

Comment: no as i am learner i have just created grid till now.

Comment: i have created below files-       Block(folder)-adminhtml(folder)-Feedback.php and Feedback(folder)-Grid.php

Comment: create a form and all then you will redirected to that form and error will autometically solved

Comment: how to create that form.and where to create that.. i mean to say what to write.. or which site should i refer to create other things

Answer (score 0):

This function is creating the row url. When you click on row it will go on controller **editAction**. change `edit` to `detail`

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/detail', array('id' => $row->getId()));
    }
```

and create `detailAction` in your admin controller

```
detailAction {

     echo 'here will come';

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> AS user asked for refer link that's why I suggesting this links

You need to create form, follow below blogs which will help you to create form and rest of the things

http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/

https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/admin-grid-magento-tutorial.html